# AWS Elasticache - memcached got high conn_yields

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I'm using the memcached module on AWS Elasticache in my lambda function.
When I telnet the endpoint and get some stats, I found some items get high values. Ex. conn_yields.
Refer to this article (https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/fine-tuning-memcached), it seems I need to adjust -R value.
But which parameter is related to "-R" option in AWS elasticache's memcahed parameter group ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `requests_per_event` parameter, which matches the [-R flag](https://linux.die.net/man/1/memcached). From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/ParameterGroups.Memcached.html):

> **requests_per_event**
>
> **Default:** 20
>
> **Type:** integer
>
> **Modifiable:** No
>
> The maximum number of requests per event for a given connection. This
>   limit is required to prevent resource starvation.